# error on npm install -g protractor

Tags: node.js, 64-bit, npm, protractor, platform

When I install protractor I get this error:

```
C:\Users\andreir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'validation.vcxproj' is invalid. Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Users\andreir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\andreir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.38
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I don't understand where the erorr is...

I have (relevant):
Windows 8.1 pro x64,
Python 2.7.10,
VS 2012 Pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue, as the error is saying, is due to the compilation of `utf-8-validate` module required by `WebSocket` required by `selenium-webdriver`

```
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
```

the compiler is failing to find a project configuration for x64

```
The Platform for project 'validation.vcxproj' is invalid. Platform='x64'
```

In this [Github Issue](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/issues/63) the solution was reinstalling VisualStudio and Windows SDK.

Anyway this is an optional dependency so you can do without it, while you figure it out, running

```
npm install --no-optional
```

Comment: Helped by installing VS2010. Thank you!