# UnknownError: null protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, end-to-end, e2e-testing

I am following [this tutorial](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial)

I followed steps except according [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30499817/492258)
instead of

```
npm install -g protractor
```

I applied

```
npm install -g protractor --no-optional
```

I successfully completed [Step 0 - write a test](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial#step-0-write-a-test)

```
expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
```

However when I try  [Step 1 - interacting with elements](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial#step-1-interacting-with-elements)

```
element(by.model('first')).sendKeys(1);
```

it gives error:

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
F

Failures:

  1) Protractor Demo App should add one and two
   Message:
     UnknownError: null
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: null
   //... continue stack trace
```

I can see that I can access dom element by testing:

```
element(by.model('firstXXX')).sendKeys(1);
```

then it says,

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.model("firstXXX")
```

What could be reason for error message mentioned above:

```
Message:
     UnknownError: null
```

Also output from `webdriver-manager start` console:

```
16:41:27.526 INFO - Executing: [send keys: null null, [1]])
16:41:27.527 WARN - Exception thrown
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SendKeys.call(SendKeys.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SendKeys.call(SendKeys.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16:41:27.530 WARN - Exception: null
16:41:27.658 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 157e0397-52e0-4d03-b8ee-aef453cd83a2])
16:41:28.843 INFO - Done: [delete session: 157e0397-52e0-4d03-b8ee-aef453cd83a2]
```

Comment: Which Chrome version are you testing against? Have you executed `webdriver-manager update`? Have you tried to run your tests with [`directConnect`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/example/conf.js)?

Comment: Did you try passing a string? `element(by.model('first')).sendKeys('1');`

Comment: @alecxe directConnect did the trick. Thanks a lot. If you can put it in answer then I could mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should resolve your problems when you use `seleniumAddress`, but you can also automate Chrome and Firefox with `directConnect`, example config is [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/example/conf.js).